# Import a List of Functions From a Text File in Maple

Tags: math-software, maple

I have a text file that is filled by the so many functions like this

[x ^ 12 + x ^ 2 + 1 , x ^ 18 + x ^ 3 + 1 , ... , x ^ 15 + x^ 14 + x ^ 5]$\quad$ (1)

I want to use this text file in Maple software. The easy method is that I define a variable in Maple such as R and copy and past this list after R in Maple, like this

R:=[x ^ 12 + x ^ 2 + 1 , x ^ 18 + x ^ 3 + 1 , ... , x ^ 15 + x^ 14 + x ^ 5] $\quad$
(2)

and after that by the command R[i] I can access to these functions. The problem of this method is that when I past this list in Maple, the speed of evaluation the command (2) is so slow for large size of (1).

The other methods is to use commands  *ImportData()* and *readdata* in Maple, but did not work. In fact, the output of these commands is not a list that I can use it (Maybe I do not know how to use these commands. I think the space between x, ^, + and numbers may cause this problem ).

*My question:* How to import a  list of functions from a text file in Maple such that the format of output be a list of functions.

Thanks.

*Edition:* 
Based on the fabulous answer of Mr. Skoog, I want to explain my original question that made this post.

Consider the following array of functions (for large size($>10^4$) is not possible to use list)
$$
\left( x+1 \right) ^{2},{x}^{3},{x}^{4}, \left( x+1 \right)  \left( 
{x}^{2}+x+1 \right) {x}^{2}, \left( {x}^{3}+{x}^{2}+1 \right) ^{2},
 \left( x+1 \right)  \left( {x}^{6}+x+1 \right) , \left( x+1 \right) ^
{4},x \left( x+1 \right) ,x \left( x+1 \right) \tag{3}
$$
In the rest, I need to obtain list of simple factors of this array without repetition, which mean
$$
[x,x+1,{x}^{2}+x+1,{x}^{3}+{x}^{2}+1,{x}^{6}+x+1]
$$
To get this, first I obtained the *lcm* command of this array $(3)$ as follows 
$$
{x}^{4} \left( {x}^{2}+x+1 \right)  \left( {x}^{3}+{x}^{2}+1 \right) ^
{2} \left( {x}^{6}+x+1 \right)  \left( x+1 \right) ^{4}\tag{4}
$$
After that I get CodeGeneration['Matlab'] of $(4)$ which is

x ^ 4 * (x ^ 2 + x + 1) * (x ^ 3 + x ^ 2 + 1) ^ 2 * (x ^ 6 + x + 1) * (x + 1) ^ 4 $\tag{5}$

And next I copy $(5)$ in a text file and with Notepad++, I removed symbols (, ) and ^ *. Then I copy the last result in Maple.

Maybe there is a simple solution for my question and because of this I made this edition.

Comment: This would be better asked on a Maple forum, not a mathematics forum.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Maybe you right. But notice that Maple is a math software and because of two tags *math-software* and *Maple* I asked this question here. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider importing the information as a string and then doing a few simple operations on the string. Since you didn't post the original file, I'll assume that you have a file, data.txt, that contains a series of expressions, something like:

```
x ^ 12 + x ^ 2 + 1 , x ^ 18 + x ^ 3 + 1 , x ^ 15 + x^ 14 + x ^ 5
```

You can first import the sequence using the [FileTools:-Text:-ReadFile](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=FileTools/Text/ReadFile) command:

```
input := FileTools:-Text:-ReadFile("data.txt");
```

This is imported to Maple as:

```
"x ^ 12 + x ^ 2 + 1 , x ^ 18 + x ^ 3 + 1 , x ^ 15 + x^ 14 + x ^ 5"
```

Next do some StringTools operations in order to make the string parseable (note that you might need to experiment with this a bit in order to make it work with your original data).

[Delete](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=StringTools/DeleteSpace) all spaces:

```
R := StringTools:-DeleteSpace(input);
```

Returns:

```
"x^12+x^2+1,x^18+x^3+1,x^15+x^14+x^5"
```

[Split](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=StringTools/Split) the data by the comma delimiter:

```
R := StringTools:-Split(R,",");
```

Returns:

```
["x^12+x^2+1", "x^18+x^3+1", "x^15+x^14+x^5"]
```

[Parse](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=parse) the data in order to make the string expressions into Maple math expressions:

```
R := parse~(R);
```

Returns:

```
[x^12+x^2+1, x^18+x^3+1, x^15+x^14+x^5]
```

Comment: Mr. Skoog, it is not an answer, it is a fabulous answer. Really thank you. I made a edition to clarify my original question.

Comment: Is it possible to ask you to help me, How to export a matrix as *Matrix market" in my hard (such as desktop of my windows) by the command-line in Maple. I know that with the right click on a matrix and selecting export as Matrix Market can be done it but how do it this action with the command-line of Maple.  I appreciate you for addressing this command. Thanks.

Comment: I would try the ExportMatrix command: https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=ImportMatrix

Comment: I saw this command but for  the export case is not clear how to save matrix in computer.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would work for your data, but how about something like:
ExportMatrix("C:/Temp/Out.mm", data, target=MatrixMarket);
If that doesn't work, perhaps you can ask another question regarding this topic either here or on the Maple user community: https://www.mapleprimes.com/